# checked box need to be click 2 time to make it check i have tried with onclick as well it is giving same behaviour i need to disable button oncheck

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**react js **
what I want is when i check any checkbox from the table in the particular button gets disabled but i have to click the checkbox two times to make it check i have also tried with onClick it is also giving the same output Please help me i am get the data through api call form localost only in useEffect and storing the data in a state Array with addon key to make
checkbox checked and button disabled and the state checked is to toggel the value of checkbox and button; *But the only problem is User have to click it 2 times i am not able to figure out*

```
const Table1 = () => {
const [supervisors, setSupervisors] = useState([]);
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
const fetchTableList = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios("http://localhost:4000/users");
  let newData = data.map((item) => {
    item.checked = false;
    item.disabled = false;
    return item;
  });

  setSupervisors(newData);
};
fetchTableList();
}, []);

console.log(supervisors);

return (
<div className="table-component" style={{ minHeight: "91vh" }}>
  <h2 className="main-heading text-center">Supervisor Mapping</h2>
  <Table striped bordered hover className="table text-center">
    <thead className="heading">
      <tr style={{ fontSize: "1.125rem" }}>
        <th className="table-heading">OID</th>
        <th className="table-heading">Supervisor </th>
        <th className="table-heading">Title</th>
        <th className="table-heading">Project</th>
        <th className="table-heading">Industry</th>
        <th className="table-heading">Supervisee</th>
        <th className="table-heading">Receiver</th>
        <th className="table-heading">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {supervisors.map((item, index) => (
        <tr key={item.supervisorId} style={{ fontSize: "0.938rem" }}>
          <td>{item.supervisorId}</td>
          <td className="mx-5">{item.supervisor} </td>
          <td>{item.title}</td>
          <td>{item.project}</td>
          <td>{item.industry}</td>
          <td
            style={
              item.supervisee.length > 5
                ? { backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }
                : item.supervisee.length > 1
                ? { backgroundColor: "yellowgreen", color: "white" }
                : { backgroundColor: "#FFD580", color: "white" }
            }
          >
            {item.supervisee.length}{" "}
          </td>
          <td>
            {" "}
            <input
              className="checkBox"
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={() => {
                setChecked(!checked);
                item.checked = checked;
              }}
              checked={item.checked}
            />
          </td>
          <td>
            <Button
              className="fas fa-eye"
              disabled={item.checked}
              id={index}
              data-id={item.supervisorId}
              data-name={item.supervisor}
            ></Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mutate the state directly.

```
onChange={() => {
  setChecked(!checked);
  item.checked = checked; //
}}
checked={item.checked}
```

Always update a clone of the state.

```
onChange={() => {
  // create a clone of the supervisors array 
  const newSupervisors = supervisors.slice(0);

  // mutate the cloned array
  newSupervisors[index].checked = !item.checked;

  // replace the state with the mutated clone
  setSupervisors(newSupervisors);
}}
```

This is not necessary.

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
```

Comment: but need to know why can,t we  directly mutate the state

Comment: If you mutate the state React won't re-render the component, so you won't see any changes. In your situation you mutate item.checked when the checkbox is clicked but the change isn't visible, but the update is happening in a second time when the checked state changes.